# Locating/Fixing Error in Function Show Distribution

Tags: c++

In the code for frequency analysis, Dev C++ keeps kicking back that I need a ';' after my argument (labeled) but this is incorrect. Adding it would void the function process and even when added, it creates more errors than it solved. Need a second eye to look it over Thank you.

I have been looking over it for hours, cannot figure out the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int token;
int alphabet[26];
int loCaseA = 97;
int loCaseZ = 122;


int getCharacter(void)
{
    char inChar;
    int result;

    cin >> inChar;

    tolower(inChar);

    result = (inChar - 'A') + 1;

return result;

}

int showDistribution(alphabet[token]) ///Here\\\

{
    char dChar;

    for(i = int loCaseA; i < int loCaseZ; i++)
{
    char dChar = '0' + i;
    cout<< dChar << "  " << alphabet[i-loCaseA]<<endl;

}


}

int main(void)
{
    for(i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
    alphabet[token] = 0;
    }

    cout << "Please enter your text." << endl;

for(i = alphabet[token]; !cin.eof(); i++)
{

    getCharacter(void);

    token = result;

    if (token < loCaseA || token > loCaseZ)
    {
        token = token - loCaseA;

    }

    else
        break;

}

showDistribution(alphabet[token]);

return 0;
}
```

Again, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int showDistribution(alphabet[token]) ///Here\\
```

As a start there is no data type specified.  You probably need for something like this.

```
int showDistribution(int *alphabet) ///Here\\
```

There are other issues in the program as well.  You need to read up on function arguments.  They need a data type at a minimum.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.